# Table color creates display issues

Tags: tables

I want to make odd rows colored to make table more readable. I'm using grey color which should be neutral enough. But for reasons unknown it creates issues with displaying the table. Vertical and horizontal lines in colored rows no longer display, but it's based on zoom level - on bigger zoom they are visible. Unfortunately it affects also print, they aren't visible on printed paper.

Example below. This might not be the prettiest table, but it also shows the glitch.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.83, 0.83, 0.83}

\title{test}
\author{Anon }
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\large
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}||c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Description} \\
\cline{2-4}
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\hline
\rowcolor{rowcol}
A & 11 & 11 & 11 \\
\hline
B & 12 & 11 & 12 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{rowcol}
C & 12 & 12 & 12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Caption} \label{tablelabel}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is depends on used prf viewer. For example, in my Sumatra or Adobe Acrobat Reader lines are clear visible However, to be on safe side, try to use `nicematrix` package. For trable lines you may also try to use `hhline` package.

Comment: see the colortbl manual cline is explictly not supported

Comment: @Zarko it's broken for me in Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can this problem be bypassed?

Comment: the colortbl manual does document alternative to cline :-) (`\hhline`) or use newer packages like `nicematrix` or `tabularray`  or (better:-) don't use rules at the same time as coloured pannels

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hhline doesn't fix the issue. Colored row still doesn't display vertical and horizontal lines. I will check alternatives but it already took me a week to make that table so I might not make it.

Comment: cline explicitly goes behind the color so can not work. hhline does not but the rules "touch" the colour panel so at some zoom levels some pdf readers lose the rules snapping to pixel boundaries. I can not do anything about that in colortbl.